# openpyxl formula not change with insert or delete operation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

```
def insert_cols(self, idx, amount=1):
    """
    Insert column or columns before col==idx
    """
    self._move_cells(min_col=idx, offset=amount, row_or_col="column")
```

After i use the insert function in openpyxl, the original formula in the excel file will still keep the same, for example, for one cell, its formula is "=A1", after i insert one column at col=1, i think this formula should be auto changed to "B1"， but it still keep "A1", how could i make it changed followed the excel col or row information changed by using openpyxl?

Comment: From the openpyxl docs; "Openpyxl does not manage dependencies, such as formulae, tables, charts, etc., when rows or columns are inserted or deleted. This is considered to be out of scope for a library that focuses on managing the file format. As a result, client code must implement the functionality required in any particular use case."

Comment: If you used xlwings api instead then it would preserve the reference.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the library documentation explains the situation.